# ReasonReact unsafe string to element

Tags: string, reason, reason-react

I made a function that takes an string and replace a specific substring within it:

```
let mark = (str: string, sub: string) : string => {
    let re = Js.Re.fromString("(" ++ sub ++ ")");
    Js.String.replaceByRe(re, "<mark>$1</mark>", str);
};
```

It works as expected. The problem is that, when using `ReasonReact.stringToElement` it escapes the string, probably for security reasons. However, I do need a way to transform my string in elements unsafely, so the `<mark>` tag inside it becomes a valid HTML. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dangerouslytSetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

It translates almost exactly syntactically to ReasonReact:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ "__html": "<mark>whatever</mark>" } />
```